# mod_rewrite won't let me load .php-files (but any other file)?

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, internal

This .htaccess-file seems to do what it should at about 15 different webhosts, except one.
Everything except url:s containing the folder "wwwdocs" should be handled by /index.php

Everything works fine even at this webhost, except it won't let me load .php-files inside the wwwdocs-folder (anything else goes: .css, .js, .jpg, .png and so on, in wwwdocs/ and its sub-folders).

The webhost's support tells me that "*You get a redirect-loop which Apache terminates after 10 iterations"*, but gives me no clues on how to solve this problem, except "perhaps using `END` instead of `L` at `RewriteRule ^(.*)wwwdocs/(.*)$ /wwwdocs/$2 [L]`" (didn't work, though).

Trying to load any .php-file in wwwdocs/ or its sub-folders will result in a **500 Internal Server Error**.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong here?:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteCond %{request_uri} !^/wwwdocs
    RewriteCond %{request_uri} !^/index\.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)wwwdocs/(.*)$ /wwwdocs/$2 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It seems you have a loop somewhere.

Comment: @Steve - Well I'm asking cause I don't know this stuff!!11 :-P I suppose you're reffering to the RewriteRule ^(.*)wwwdocs/(.*)$ /wwwdocs/$2 [L] - any suggestions on how to fix that? Without having to rewrite every piece of php-code that uses the wwwdocs-folder?